# How to use Autofac to initialize your own components?

Tags: botframework

I would like to use Autofac IOC container in my bot application (based on BotFramework).

I can see that framework itself already uses it.

But I can't figure out how to do it gracefully... I don't want to resolve my components on every post invocation (it will slow down my post method execution).

I appreciate if you share code snippets with your solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Autofac container being used in the framework in the Global.asax and perform your own registrations.

The key code pieces are:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// perform your registrations on the builder

// update the container being used by the framework
builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

For a real implementation of this, you could take a look to the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample where you will see that a Module is used to register the application specific components. Here is the [Global.asax](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Global.asax.cs) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowersModule.cs) the actual module.