# bot framework and repositry design pattern dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm creating an Bot Application using Luis and Luis Action Binding like the following sample 
[Luis action binding sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding)

I want to use dependency injection to pass the data service instance to the action binding

I add a data layer following repository design pattern like that:

```
public class ProviderService : IProviderService
{
    private readonly IProviderRepository ProviderRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    public ProviderService(IProviderRepository providerService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.ProviderRepository = providerService;
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void CreateProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        ProviderRepository.Add(provider);
    }
```

and will use it from the fulfill method in the action binding class like that

```
 public class FindNumberAction : BaseLuisAction
{
    IProviderService _provider;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a ProviderName")]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    public string ProviderType { get; set; }

    public FindNumberAction() : this(new ProviderService(new ProviderRepository(new DbFactory()), new UnitOfWork(new DbFactory())))
    {

    }

    public FindNumberAction(IProviderService provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public override Task<object> FulfillAsync()
    {
        var providerData = _provider.GetByProviderName(Provider);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(providerData.ProviderAddress))
        {
            var result = new ProviderInfo
            {
                ProviderAddress = providerData.ProviderAddress,
                ProviderName = providerData.Provider.ProviderName,
                ProviderPhone = providerData.ProviderPhone,
                ProviderType = providerData.Provider.ProviderType.ProviderTypeName
            };
            return Task.FromResult((object)result.GetNumber());
        }

        return Task.FromResult((object)new ProviderInfo() { ProviderName = Provider, ProviderType = ProviderType }.NoProviderNumberFound());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to use dependency injection for providerservice instead of creating the instance manually  in findnumberaction

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826517/how-to-use-autofac-to-initialize-your-own-components

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot

Here is a great example of how to implement AutoFac in the bot framework. You'll see that you not only need to implement the container, but also have to change the way the MessagesController handles the incomming messages.